# How do you light the random oil lamps found throughout the world?

Tags: ps4, far-cry-4

I've run across some oil lamps a couple of times now, once in a hidden cave and also at the top of a bell tower.  The lamps flash, the same way loot chests flash, so I'm assuming there's a way to light them, however I don't have any matches and the only flammable item I have is the Molotov cocktail. I've attached a photo of the one I found in the bell tower.

So how do you light them?

[image]

Comment: I understand that the rating system is not meant to work this way, but I upvoted this question simply for the humor value (even if it was unintentional on Alan's part).  I can relate, though;  lots of times certain things on games will look like something else to me, and it may take me forever to figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a mine to me. Are you sure it's an oil lamp? Next time when you encounter that object, just waste a mine and see if you can pick it up.

Comment: Those are mines, DERP. rofl oil lamps...

Comment: D'oh!  I thought for sure that I had walked over them in an attempt to pick them up, so obviously my inventory was already full, which made me think they were something other than ammo.  :-)